# dotnet new blazor error when build and run

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-code, .net-core, blazor

I have `dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-preview3-010431-win-x64` zip binary file and extracted it to `C:\dotnet` and add this path to the user variables path. 
I had dotnet 2.2 before in that path and I deleted it and paste new version(preview3-010431) to create a blazor project.

`dotnet` can create and run webapp project correctly but not blazor.
First I executed this command :

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::0.9.0-preview3-19154-02
```

When i run:

```
dotnet new blazor -o WebApplication1
cd WebApplication1
```

It is ok. But `dotnet build` does not work and I get the error :

> "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.9.0-preview3-19154-02\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(439,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "dotnet
>   "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.8.0-preview-20190204.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/illink/illink.dll" -l none --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.8.0-preview-20190204.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/"
>   -d "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.8.0-preview-20190204.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "E:\Projects\WebApplication1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/"
>   -x "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.9.0-preview3-19154-02\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml"
>   -x "E:\Projects\WebApplication1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\0.9.0-preview3-19154-02\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\3.0.0-preview3-19153-02\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.browser\3.0.0-preview3-19153-02\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.6.0-preview3.19128.7\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   -a "E:\Projects\WebApplication1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\WebApplication1.dll""
>   exited with code -2147450730.
>   [E:\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.9.0-preview3-19154-02\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(439,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "dotnet
>   "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.8.0-preview-20190204.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/illink/illink.dll" -l none --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.8.0-preview-20190204.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/"
>   -d "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.8.0-preview-20190204.1\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "E:\Projects\WebApplication1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/"
>   -x "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.9.0-preview3-19154-02\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml"
>   -x "E:\Projects\WebApplication1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\0.9.0-preview3-19154-02\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\3.0.0-preview3-19153-02\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.browser\3.0.0-preview3-19153-02\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\3.0.0-preview3.19153.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll"
>   -a "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.6.0-preview3.19128.7\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   -a "E:\Projects\WebApplication1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\WebApplication1.dll""
>   exited with code -2147450730.
>   [E:\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj] 0 Warning(s) 1
>   Error(s)"

I deleted all packages in C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages , but error exist. I deleted all files and folders in C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.dotnet too , but error exist.

After I run:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates
```

And then build, I get this error :

> "C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\RazorCompilation.targets(184,5):
>   error : rzc generate exited with code -2147450730.
>   [E:\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users\sap-komaei.CII.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\RazorCompilation.targets(184,5):
>   error : rzc generate exited with code -2147450730.
>   [E:\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj] 0 Warning(s) 1
>   Error(s)"

Comment: Why don't you run the setup of the dotnet installer instead of only extracting it? That won't work..

Comment: It works for other project template.
And I can not install any application on my pc in my work for network policies.

Comment: I install dotnet 3.0.100-preview3-010431 on my home labtop and blazor project builded but console project not build and get error :

Comment: message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview [D:\MyProjects\Core\Console\Console.csproj]
Program.cs(9,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WriteLine' does not exist in the namespace 'Console' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

I figured out.

for build the blazor template we must install both dotnet core v3 preview and the latest 2.2 version. I can not install any application on my work pc. So I use portable versions.

resolution for me:

1. copy E:\My Pro\DotNetCore\dotnet-sdk-2.2.105-win-x64\sdk\2.2.105 folder to my installation sdk path (E:\dotnet\sdk)
2. copy E:\My Pro\DotNetCore\dotnet-sdk-2.2.105-win-x64\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.3 folder to E:\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App.
3. add E:\dotnet\ & E:\dotnet\host\fxr\3.0.0-preview3-27503-5\ & E:\My Pro\VS Code\1.32.1\ to user path variable.
4. add E:\dotnet\ to DOTNET_ROOT variable.